# Calculation of $\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{−x} − e^{−ux}}{ x} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

Validate the following identity by differentiation. Using  Mean Value Theorem.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{−x} − e^{−ux}}{ x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \log u , \qquad u ≥ 1.$$

I am not sure what am I mean to do here? Do I need to find the derivative of the integral or the log u?

**EDIT:**

- Step 1: Find the derivative of the upper limit and then substitute the upper limit into the integrand. Multiply both results.
- Step 2: Find the derivative of the lower limit and then substitute the lower limit into the integrand. Multiply both results.
- Step 3: Subtract the above results in order.

Is this how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: [Differentiating the integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) with respect to $u$ should give you $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}u}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-ux}}{x}\text{ d}x=\int_0^\infty\frac{-e^{-ux}}{x}(-x)\text{ d}x=\int_0^\infty e^{-ux}\text{ d}x=1/u$, which is the same derivative as that of $\log u$. Further establishing that both functions share the value $0$ at $u=1$ shows that they must be equal. The MVT is needed to show that differentiation under the integral is valid (see the wiki page)

Comment: @PhoboHavuz I suggest applying the same procedure to the integral $\int\limits_a^b$ and then calculate the limit when $a\to 0^+$ and $b\to \infty.$ In this way justification of ${d\over du}\int\limits_a^bf(x,u)\,dx=\int\limits_a^b{\partial f\over \partial u}f(x,u)\,dx$ is easy as we are dealing with proper integrals.